# Can we develop an application using C++ with cgi support in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, cgi

I want to make an application using C++ code and want to integrate it using cgi to make it webapplication.

But, I don't know is it possible to develop it in Visual studio 2010.

Comment: I personally think that C++ is often a poor choice for a web application.  But it's your funeral.  Yes, it is absolutely possible to do in VS2010.  You should investigate the CGI mechanisms of your `http` server.  Are you using Apache?

Answer (score 2):

A CGI program is a normal program that just behaves in a certain way (reads stuff from standard input/writes stuff to standard output).

You can developed it in Visual Studio, but the simple C++ compiler will do it  as well.